# MVVMCross User Interaction Patterns using Interaction Request Objects?

Tags: mvvmcross

In Prims, there are two common approaches to implementing user interactions in the MVVM pattern. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec10
 1. Implement a service that can be used by the view model to initiate interaction with the user
 2. Uses events raised by the view model to express the intent to interact with the user, along with components in the view that are bound to these events and that manage the visual aspects of the interaction.

I think MvxPresentationHint should be the first approach. How about support the second approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe anyone has implemented any formal documented common cross-platform `dialog` interaction patterns between viewmodel and view at this stage.

I personally have used several mechanisms including :

- using a messenger for the viewmodel to send a general 'ask y/n' request and then for the view to send an 'answer was y/n' response.
- using a custom presenter to override ShowViewModel behaviour with a popup dialog

Both of these approaches worked well, were testable, used only a small amount of 'code behind', provided easy customization and used only weak references - so didn't cause any memory issues in iOS. In general, where faced with similar ux requirements in the future I think I'd consider the messenger approach as my first choice - but that's a personal design preference - not some 'best practice' essay like in prism.

Comment: When using messenger approach ( e.g. MvxMessenger ), it is a global service to handle interaction between all view and viewmodel. What I suggest is more local approach for a view and viewmodel pair. i.e. viewmodel raise an generic event to its view, thus the view execute certain function.

Comment: Excellent - thanks - I look forwards to reading about your progress somewhere.